# How can I redirect audio over network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I'm using an Ubuntu box, I need to redirect all audio stream from my local sound card over my network. This audio stream has to be played on a remote computer. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could install rdesktop http://www.rdesktop.org/ then connect to it via a Windows computer configuring the session to move audio to the remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, have a look at setting up PulseAudio to run over your network - http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to simply send audio over TCP. My need was therefore slightly different but here is something that I think is pointing in the right direction for you:

[How to redirect sound from microphone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116919/redirect-sound-microphone-via-ssh-how-to-telephone-via-ssh)

However it requires that you start the "player" externally. I suspect that by adding another utility like "[jack](http://www.jackaudio.org/)" you could achieve what you want.